# Extract information from a webpage in a particular format

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to make a simple python script to extract certain links from a [webpage](http://mp3skull.com/mp3/linkin_park_faint.html). I am able to extract link successfully but now I want to extract some more information like `bitrate,size,duration` given on that webpage.

I am using the below xpath to extract the above mentioned info

```
>>> doc = lxml.html.parse('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/linkin_park_faint.html')
>>> info = doc.xpath(".//*[@id='song_html']/div[1]/text()")
>>> info[0:7]
['\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t3.71 mb\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t3.49 mb\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t192 kbps', '2:41']
```

Now what I need is that for a particular link the info I require is generated in a form of `tuple` like `(bitrate,size,duration)`.

The `xpath` I mentioned above generates the required info but it is `ill-formatted` that is it is not possible to achieve my required format with any logic at least I am not able to that.

So, is there any way to achieve the output in my format.?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Do you need it returned in the same tuple format as in your example? e.g. "(192 kbps, 3.49 mb, 2:41)" in text?

Comment: @JWiley: No, any format will work

Comment: @JWiley: It will also work if we can just show this information for the `first five links`.

Comment: You can do that by adding a snippet to your XPath to strip all the nonsense out, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I think BeautifulSoup will do the job, it parses even badly formatted HTML:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

parsing is quite easy with BeautifulSoup - for example:

```
import bs4
import urllib
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/linkin_park_faint.html').read())

print soup.find_all('a')
```

and have quite good docs:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

How are you with regular expressions and python's re module?

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html may be essential.

As far as getting the data out of the array, `re.match(regex,info[n])` should suffice, as far as the triple tuple goes, the python tuple syntax takes care of it. Simply match from members of your info array with re.match.

```
import re


matching_re = '.*'    # this re matches whole strings, rather than what you need
incoming_value_1 = re.match(matching_re,info[1])
# etc. 
var truple = (incoming_value_1, incoming_value_2, incoming_value_2
```

Comment: So, basically you are asking me to load my complete html into a string and parse it using regular expressions.

Comment: Nope, just to match from your already extracted array info[]. From the relevant member of info[], eg, match the digits with precede mb in info[1] to get what I am guessing is your size variable. My last example was overkill to use group on different members of array.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually strip everything out with XPath:

```
translate(.//*[@id='song_html']/div[1]/text(), "\n\t,'", '')
```

So for your additional question, either:

```
info[0, len(info)]
```

for altogether, or:

```
info.rfind(" ")
```

Since the translate leaves a space character, but you could replace that with whatever you wanted.

Addl info found [here](http://www.astro.ufl.edu/~warner/prog/python.html)

Comment: when I use your XPath it returns a list of length=0. My code: `xp = '''translate(.//*[@id='song_html']/div[1]/text(), "\n\t ,", '')'''` and than `t = doc.xpath(xp)` so now len(t) =0.

Comment: I tried it on the fragment "['\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t3.71 mb\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t3.49 mb\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t192 kbps', '2:41']" myself and got " 3.71 mb  3.49 mb  192 kbps 2:41" Did you not use the code you originally posted?

Comment: If I undesrstand your xpath will just perform a `clean up` of the output I am getting but still It is not what I want because how will I associate the output with each link.

Comment: I used that code only.Have a look here am i using the xpath correctly http://pastie.org/3962469

Comment: For example `1st and 2nd` link only have `size` defined for them and 3rd link has all (`size,length,duration`) defined for it. So, how will I assign these value to each link from your o/p `3.71 mb 3.49 mb 192 kbps 2:41"`.

Comment: Well initially your question was just asking for formatted output. If the values are always in that order, you could use substrings to grab each one. I can't see the site you linked, it's blocked where I am.